# How to use Qt Linguist for Qt UI file?

Tags: qt, user-interface, translation, linguistics

I am using Qt linguist to translate a `ui` file. I obtained its `ts` file using `lupdate`, and translated those words and phrases. Now I want to add it to my code, but I found from its tutorial that seems like I have to add `tr()` to each and every single word and phrase in my code. Did I understand it correctly? Can I just load the translated `qm` file once to do the translation? If so, how can I do it in this `ui` file?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

After changing the properties as Jens mentioned, in my ui header file I can see sentences like:

```
buttonSetupData->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Set Data", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
```

After Ajith's answer, I've changed my code, and now my `retranslateUi` function in `ui_main.h` file looks like this:

```
void retranslateUi ( QMainWindow *MainWindow )
{
    QTranslator translator;
    translator.load ( " ...\Test.ts " );
    QApplication::installTranslator ( &translator );

    MainWindow->setWindowTitle ( QApplication::translate ("MainWindow",  "The Sentioscope - Beta v2.0 for Soccer", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));

    ...
}
```

But it still didn't work.

**latest update**

My current function for reading ".qm" file is like this:

```
void MainWindow::translate()
{
     QTranslator translator;
     translator.load ( "Test.qm", "D:\\" );
     qApp->installTranslator ( &translator );
     retranslateUi ( this );
 }
```

Then I call this function like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow ( QWidget *parent ) : QMainWindow ( parent )
{
    setupUi(this);
    translate();
}
```

After Ajith's latest answer, I changed each string for warning/message boxes in this form (for example):

```
QMessageBox::warning( this, QMessageBox::tr("ERROR"), QMessageBox::tr("Invalid IP adress") );
```

By `lupdate` I can read all these strings, translate, and save them in a qm file. The problem now is, it can translate those strings for ui, but not for warning/message boxes after execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about what you want to accomplish from the question. I think you are looking for a way to load the "qm" files at runtime from C++ code. If so, what you will need to do is use the [QTranslator](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtranslator.htm) class..

```
QTranslator translator;
translator.load("file.qm", "dir");
qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
```

**Update**

This was working for me..

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    isChinese(false)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    msgbox = new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::NoIcon, "", "", QMessageBox::NoButton, this);
    pbtn = msgbox->addButton("Ok", QMessageBox::AcceptRole);

    doRetranslate();

    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(doTranslate()));
    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), msgbox, SLOT(show()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::doTranslate()
{
    QTranslator translator;
    if (!isChinese) {
        translator.load("test_zh_TW.qm", "../TestTranslator");
        qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
        isChinese = true;
    } else {
        translator.load("", ""); // Default is english
        qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
        isChinese = false;
    }
    ui->retranslateUi(this);
    doRetranslate();
}

void MainWindow::doRetranslate()
{
    msgbox->setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("ERROR"));
    msgbox->setText(QObject::tr("Invalid IP adress"));
    pbtn->setText(QObject::tr("Ok"));
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void doRetranslate();
public slots:
    void doTranslate();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    bool isChinese;
    QMessageBox *msgbox;
    QPushButton *pbtn;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>70</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>17</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Hello World!</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>140</x>
      <y>120</y>
      <width>93</width>
      <height>27</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>translate</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>pushButton</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>label</receiver>
   <slot>update()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>199</x>
     <y>165</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>206</x>
     <y>114</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

Comment: I want to load it in the ui or its header file, not in the cpp, because I've tried it exactly as you mentioned, but it failed.

Comment: I don't know if it can be done from the .ui file during run-time. But for the method I suggested, you will need to do a reload of the widgets already displayed. Something like `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "doReload", Qt::QueuedConnection);`

Comment: This link may be of use [http://qtcenter.org/wiki/index.php?title=Dynamic_translation_in_Qt4_applications&oldid=2307].. It mentions that, "All forms designed in the Qt Designer have a method called retranslateUi(). This must be called in order to make designed strings retranslated"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question according it.

Comment: translator.load ( " ...\Test.ts " ); <--- You need to provide the .qm file.

Comment: Just one more question: seems like 'lupdate' cannot find text strings in warning windows. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Should not be an lupdate issue. lupdate just scans the text files and strings the strings tagged with the translate() function, and populates the .ts file. Check the source files to make sure the strings you want are tagged with the tr() or translate() functions.

Comment: In the source file, those strings for warnings are all with tr or translate() functions, but lupdate still cannot find them. That is what confuses me.

Comment: I never encountered such an issue with lupdate. So I couldn't say.

Comment: Ok, I've solved it. Now it can read all those strings in the warnings. But with that I have another qm file, that means together with qm for ui, I have totally two qm files. And in my code when I read both of them with two lines and do retranslateUi, it only translates the ui, but not the warnings. How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: There is no need for two qm files. The result of lupdate should all be in one ts file, under different contexts. As a test, I think you should try to run lupdate from the command line. I cannot test it right now, but try 'lupdate *.{cpp,h} -ts test.ts'. The first parameter to QApplication::translate() is the context, manually set it to different context. You can specify different contexts and it should all go to the same ts file. Also, let me take a look at your .pro file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am always using command line for lupdate, and after your suggesion, I've tried using it as "lupdate *.{cpp,h,ui} -ts Test.ts", but it failed. Then after reading its help file, I used it as "lupdate -extensions *.{cpp,h,ui} -ts Test.ts" but the ts file is empty. Could you help me?

Comment: If using -extensions the syntax should be...'lupdate . -extensions cpp,h,ui -ts test.ts'. I was trying to use bash expansion but since at that time I did not have the environment to check my command I forgot the second argument which should be the path in this case '.' or the current dir. Anyway these extensions are included by default, there should be no need to specify them.

Comment: please allow me to ask another question: I added "tr" for each and every warning string manually, which can be detected by lupdate. Then after calling all those strings in one ts file and translated them, it still showed me the translated words for only the ui, but not for the warnings.  How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: At this point I don't really know whats happening at your end.. Can you post something I can try out in my environment..

Comment: Please take a look at this line in my code: "QMessageBox::warning( this, QMessageBox::tr("ERROR"), QMessageBox::tr("Invalid IP address") );". Then after lupdate, in the ts file, it showed the string "Invalid IP address" in "QMessageBox" part, and I translated it. But after calling the qm file, it still didn't tranlate it actually. I think the command "retranslateUi(this)" has something to do with this, but I can't tell how. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I could reproduce the problem. I am not sure why this happens. If I call the warning window before retranslateUI() it displays with translated text. Maybe you can open another question, someone else may have a better idea. 
Alternate way is to create your own warning window using...
    msgbox = new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::NoIcon, "", "", QMessageBox::NoButton, this);
    pbtn = msgbox->addButton("Ok", QMessageBox::AcceptRole);

And then have your own retranslate function only for the text in the warning window.I was able to use this to get a translated warning window.

Comment: Thank you again. At this point, I have to let it work only using not an efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much correct what you describe.
The QtDesigner/QtCreator allows for each ui-Element to select whether its texts should be translated or not (see the properties of each ui-Element). If translation is selected, then the tr() is put into the generated ui_xxx.h file and from there it is presented like any other translatable word.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me how could I use it in my ui file then? If I have a cpp file I could load the ts file as in the tutorial, but here my file is a .ui one. I saw it added "::tranlate ..." in its header file now.