# QLinguist cannot translate warning messages

Tags: qt, user-interface, linguistics, language-translation

In Qlinguist, I translated ui and some corresponding warning messages, generated `qm` file, and loaded it, but in the result it only can translate the ui, but not those warning messages. My code is like this:

```
void MainWindow::translate()
{
     QTranslator translator;
     translator.load ( "Test.qm", "D:\\" );
     qApp->installTranslator ( &translator );
     retranslateUi ( this );
}

MainWindow::MainWindow ( QWidget *parent ) : QMainWindow ( parent )
{
    setupUi(this);
    translate();
    ...
}
```

One of my warning messages is in this form:

```
QMessageBox::warning( this, QMessageBox::tr("ERROR"), QMessageBox::tr("Invalid IP adress") );
```

This string can be load by `lupdate`, and I translated it in its `qm` file, but still cannot see its translation after running. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135416/how-to-use-qt-linguist-for-qt-ui-file) I asked about it, but I have to open this new question in order to solve it with someone's help. Can someone help me on this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the translator on the stack, it will be deleted right away at the end of translate().
Try to create it on the heap instead so it lives on.